# The file “MyProgramm.ipa” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I try to upload my application to iTunes Connect I receive the following error:

> **Unable to validate your application.** The path
>   '/var/folders/5k/.../XCodeDistPipeline.AGI/Packages/MyProgramm.ipa'
>   does not contain a file.

[image]

Comment: any updates on this please. struggling with this for a cordova app

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message except that I was making an ad hoc distribution ipa file. I turned off the "Export from Bitcode" checkbox right before the final step and the ipa finally was built correctly.